# Encountered LineUnavailableException when capturing sound with Java Sound API

Tags: java, audio, capture

I am using Java Sound API to capture sound on a Windows machine by reading data from a TargetDataLine. It works fine if I open a line, read data from the line and then close it. However, If I reopen it once closed, I will get a LineUnavailableException. Can someone explain to me what is going on? If I want to record multiple sound clips, one after another, say repeating this: start -------> record ---------> stop several times, how can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/TargetDataLine.html#open-javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat-) says:

> Some lines, once closed, cannot be reopened. Attempts to reopen such
>   a line will always result in a `LineUnavailableException`.

I think the reason they say "some lines" is that it depends on external factors pertaining to the particular system.

You will need to create a line for each additional recording, it seems.